# Unity game onto Windows 8 store

Tags: unity, windows, windows-8

I've been searching around the web to see if it is possible to submit a unity game onto the windows 8 store. All I have found so far are articles months old saying it is coming soon, can anyone give me an update if this is yet possible and how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to keep this updated, the Unity Blog has details on the Windows Store early access program, Unity 4.2, and some Unity-based games already in the Windows Store:

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/03/07/unity-4-early-access-for-windows-store-apps

Answer (score 1):

I think this is as updated as you are going to get

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/350071/windows-phone-8-support.html

Comment: Thanks, I think I've read the exact same somewhere else. But as I thought we are now mid Feb we would of heard something. Hopefully some news soon. I didn't know if there was an unofficial way to do it yet.